# Define command so that \label works properly

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have something like this:

```
\newcounter{Def}
\newcommand{\printDef}{\thechapter.\thesection.\theDef}
\newenvironment{Expl}
{\small\narrower\medskip\stepcounter{Def}\noindent\ignorespaces \textsc{Example \printDef.}}
{\par\normalsize\medskip}
```

And then:

```
\begin{Expl} \label{myref}
blahblahblah
\end{Expl}
```

Suppose the current section is 2.4, then it will print something like:

> Example 2.4.1.

However, when I do `\ref{myref}`, it will just print 2.4.  The 1 is totally gone!  Could anyone please help?  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thank Caramdir for editing it!!! It looks amazing now.

Comment: You are welcome. It was just a matter of selecting text and pressing the code (marked with 101010) and quote buttons.

Comment: For your immediate example, it might be easier to use a theorem environment (e.g. from `amsmath` or `ntheorem`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change some of the code to make it work:

- You should redefine `\theDef` instead of using `\printDef`. It is used in internal code. You can add the old definition as `\arabic{Def}` which prints the counter value as normal (i.e. arabic) number.
- Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. This sets the internal macro `\@currentlabel` which is used by `\label`. Then the then current value of `\theDef` will be used in the `\ref`.

Also:

- Note that depending on the used document-class the `\thesection` macro already includes `\thechapter`. With e.g. `report` the chapter number would be printed twice. (I disabled it therefore in the example).
- The `\ignorespaces` should be at the very end to be effective.
- You don'y need to  change the font back to normal at the end because all changes are only local to the environment content anyway.
- You should add an explicit `\par` at the beginning and place the `\medskip` and `\noindent` just after it. They work at the current locations as well but this way it is much cleaner.

The working code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{Def}
\renewcommand{\theDef}{%\thechapter.
    \thesection.\arabic{Def}}
\newenvironment{Expl}
{\par\medskip\noindent\small\narrower\refstepcounter{Def}\textsc{Example~\theDef.}\ignorespaces}
{\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{A}

\begin{Expl}\label{test}
    Test
\end{Expl}

See \ref{test}.

\begin{Expl}\label{test2}
    Test2
\end{Expl}

See \ref{test2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is probably better to add it also to the section counter reset list: `\newcounter{Def}[section]`